# Scheduling tasks in vm waiting queue

Tags: cloud, cloudsim

We all know both timeshared and spaceshared in which timeshared act like round robin while spaceshared to represent fcfs based algorithms
But the problem here how to implement RR on the waiting queue for vm if we have 100 cloudlets and one vm
Please help me:
zyadnehm@Yahoo.com